# simultaneous processes in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry if this is confusing. I am going to try my best to summarize it as clean as possible.

I have a table named consignment.

```
    CREATE TABLE `consignment` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `consignment_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `account` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `hawb` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `print_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index2` (`hawb`),
  KEY `index3` (`account`),
  KEY `index4` (`consignment_status`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=841283 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

When an entry is made into this table, i set the print_status to "ready".

I show all the records from consignment table which has a consignment_status as valid in an HTML page

User then selects the records and clicks generate button to generate some pdfs.

Problems arises when 2 users open the same page and click generate for same consignments at
the same time. This way 2 PDF’s are generated for same consignment entry.

Need solution so that if one user has clicked the button to generate PDF, for the other user the code should skip those consignment entries.

What I have done so far is added an extra column in data base called print_status.

When user clicks generate button, MySQL database query is performed which selects the records for which print status is not active.

```
SELECT * FROM consignment c WHERE  c.account='1234'AND c.consignment_status='valid' AND c.print_status='ready' GROUP BY hawb  having count(*)=1 ORDER BY account, hawb
```

Right after select I do an update on same records to set the print status to active so that other processes can not select the same record.

```
  update consignment set print_status='ACTIVE' where id in (4564562)
```

This seems to be not working if 2 users click the generate button generate button at the same or near to same time and both processes are able to select records for which print_status is "ready"

Also another issue which needs to be taken care of is that lets say user A enter 5 records ( 1,2,3,4,5) and user B enters 5 records ( 6,7,8,9,10). Both users will be shown records (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10). User A then selects records ( 1,2,3) to be printed and user B selects (1,2,6,7,8) to be printed. So this case when user A goes to print the PDF's, he should be be able to print only PDF's for (3) and user B should be able to print PDF for all (1,2,6,7,8)

What is the optimum solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I Think you should call an ajax request on the page where the generate button is present every second. the request would be sent to a PHP file where you will check if the print_status is active or not. if the status is active, then you can simply return any response for example: 'already_printed' and then check on the ajax side if the response equals to already_printed, then you can just disable the button or anything you wanna do. if it is not already_printed you can just allow the user to generate it. i think you understood it.

Comment: Doing a select query every second to check if print_status is active or not is going to be bad for database?

Comment: I Really don't think so. i have been using this all the time in my projects. you should give it a try at least or you can just limit the duration to 5 or 10 seconds are per your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a race condition by selecting first then updating.

Instead, update first including the `print_status` in your `WHERE` clause:

```
update consignment set print_status='ACTIVE' where id in (4564562) and print_status != 'ACTIVE'
```

Then check the number of affected records. If it's zero the record was locked by someone else so you report that to the user. If it's not zero you've locked the record so now you can safely select it.

Comment: I like your solution. The only scenario which I can think of which needs to be taken care of if when 2 users select a mix of consignments. ( I added an edit in the question above with explanation). Can you please advise on that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with updating the table with an "I'm doing something, go away" label is if that process dies in the middle, then nothing will ever attempt to try again without bolting on more kludge and nigh-endless edge cases.

This is best accomplished with this one weird trick: Use a transaction to lock the rows in the consignment table while you're processing.

The raw SQL would look like:

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT *
  FROM consignment c
  WHERE
    c.account='1234'
    AND c.consignment_status='valid'
    AND c.print_status='ready'
  GROUP BY hawb HAVING COUNT(*)=1
  ORDER BY account, hawb
  FOR UPDATE;
-- app code executes
UPDATE consignment SET print_status='ACTIVE' WHERE id IN (4564562);
COMMIT;
```

Note the `FOR UPDATE` at the end of the select, this locks the rows for the duration of the transaction. Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

The PHP code can add a couple bells and whistles. I'm going to assume PDO here, but MySQLi has equivalents for everything here if you're using that, I'm also snipping out the bodies of the prepare/parameter calls for brevity.

```php
$dbh->beginTransaction();
// assuming that you've set the error mode to exception
try {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT ... FOR UPDATE');
    $stmt->execute([...]);
    // generate the PDF
    if( ! $pdf_success ) {
        // uh oh, everything is terrible.
        throw new MyFunException();
    }
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE consignment ...');
    $stmt->execute([...]);
    $dbh->commit();
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    // you can set multiple catch blocks for different kinds of exceptions
    // immediately roll back the transaction so nothing gets stuck waiting for the lock to release.
    $dbh->rollback();
    // maybe marked the consignment as "ERROR" and/or notify a human for review
    // re-throw the exception, unless you plan to actually handle it here
    throw $e;
}
```

Any time you need to guarantee the database's state across more than one operation, you should likely be enclosing those operations in a transaction.